# Multiple arguments and return params

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Sorry for a newbie question.

I'm designing a smart contract wherein I need to send in many( around 50) arguments to a setter method and return a list of same number of arguments in a getter. 
So basically what I'm trying to create is a database store where each record will have these many attributes and there will be many such records. 
For setter, I found out that there is something called "calldata" or "msg.data" feature which can hide a list of arguments
For getter, I need to return a two dimensional array in this case but it seems a dynamic array as return type is not supported.

I don't know if there are other ways to do this. Please suggest

Comment: I guess IPFS/Orbit-db is the way to go. Anyone ?